# Start/stop values for blocks of consecutive numbers

Tags: matlab, indexing

If I have a vector of:

```
[4,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,21,22,23]
```

How can I, *without a loop*, extract the start/end values of all consecutive number blocks i.e. the desired result for the above vector would be a 2-column vector:

```
b = 

4   7
11  14
21  23
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

```
a = [4,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,21,22,23];
b = reshape(a(sort([find(a - circshift(a,[0,1]) ~= 1),find(a - circshift(a,[0,-1]) ~= -1)])),2,[])'
```

Output:

```
b =

 4     7
11    14
21    23
```

Comment: Do you have a method that does not require the communications system toolbox?

Comment: @AnnaSchumann yes, `b = reshape(a(sort([find(a - circshift(a,[0,1]) ~= 1),find(a - circshift(a,[0,-1]) ~= -1)])),[],2)`

Comment: With `a = [2,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,21,22,23];` I get `b` equal to `[2 11;2 14;5 21;7 23]`, which seems to be incorrect

Comment: @LuisMendo let's see what I can do to fix it :)

Comment: @LuisMendo fixed :) For your case output is:
`[2     2;  5     7;  11    14;   21    23]`

Answer (score 4):

Another approach:

```
x = [4,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,21,22,23];
x = x(:);
ind = find([1; diff(x)-1; 1]);
result = [x(ind(1:end-1)) x(ind(2:end)-1)];
```

Comment: I was about to post a new question for a similar problem: My vector consists of zeros and ones, but with `find(schedule)`, I can get to the format you are using. And instead of start+end, I need start+length, which I get via `resultFinal = [result(:,1), result(:,2) - result(:,1) + 1]`. Very elegant code, spares me the `for` loop and is about twice as fast!

Comment: @rotton Glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
    v  = [4,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,21,22,23];

    dv = diff(diff(v)==1);

    bv = find(dv==+1)+1;
    if dv(1) == 0
            bv = [1,bv];
    end;

    ev = find(dv==-1)+1;
    if dv(end) == 0
            ev = [ev,numel(v)];
    end;

    b = v([bv(:),ev(:)]);
```

Comment: With `v = [2,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,21,22,23];` this seems to miss the first element

Comment: @LuisMendo It will miss all the "isolated" numbers (i.e. that don't belong to a sequence of consecutive numbers that has at least two numbers in it)

Answer (score 2):

Not the best answer, but I spend a hour to get it, so I want to post it:

```
x = (0:10:a(end))'; %'
subindex = @(A) [A(1) A(end)];
fun = @(q) subindex( a(a>q & a<q+10));
res = cell2mat(arrayfun(fun, x, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

It works for any size of `a`.

Comment: Really nice solution. Thank you!